# How can I go by proving $x < \frac{x+y}{2} < y$ when $x < y$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, logic, proof-verification

I have this exercise that asks: Prove that for all real numbers $x$ and $y$ if $x < y$, then $x < \frac{x+y}{2} < y$.

My attempt to this was like so:

Proof: Let x and y be real numbers and suppose $x < \frac{x+y}{2} < y$. Multiplying 2 to both sides gives us this expression $2x < x+y < 2y$. Then we simplify it to get $x < y$. Since we get the $x < y$, then we know its true.

Is that a correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: You are *not supposed to assume that* $x < \frac{x+y}{2} < y$, which is what you have started out with. You are supposed to start with $x < y$, and then reach the former conclusion. As it turns out, you can reverse the steps you have written to get the right proof.

Comment: I think you should be able to use the fact that $(x+y)/2$ is the average of $x$ and $y$, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг That sounds like it would make a great answer to this question.

Comment: @BrianJ Only too short.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Ah, I see. That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @KonoDioDa You are welcome. Also, +1 for your question.

Comment: Please find a better title. The title you picked would match almost **every** question in this site, and it is therefore useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started by the end.

$$x <y\implies \frac {x}{2}<\frac {y}{2} $$

$$\implies \frac {x}{2}+\frac {x}{2}<\frac {x}{2}+\frac {y}{2} $$
$$\implies x <\frac {x+y}{2} $$

this is correct.

Comment: And adding $\frac{y}{2}$ to both sides of the conclusion of the first line gives the second part BTW.

Answer (score 1):

We can do it through a proof by contradiction. Given the premise, assume that it's not the case that $x < \frac{x+y}{2} < y$, then  $x < \frac{x+y}{2}$ and $\frac{x+y}{2} < y$ and $x < y$ must all be false.

However we have from the premise that $x < y$ is true, which is a contradiction on that $x < y $ is false; so therefore our assumption must be wrong; which means the statement $x < \frac{x+y}{2} < y$ is true for when $x < y$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $$y-\frac{x+y}{2}=\frac{y-x}{2}>0$$ and
$$\frac{x+y}{2}-x=\frac{y-x}{2}>0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Often you can assume the conclusion, work towards the premise and reverse the steps but you must be careful to ensure all the steps are still valid. To modify your solution so that it's a proof we can take the following steps.

$1)$ Given $x < y$ show that $2x < x+y$

$2)$Given $x < y$ show that $x + y < 2y$

$3)$Conclude that $2 x < x+ y < 2y$

$4)$Mulitply $2x < x+ y < 2y$ though by $\frac{1}{2}$

and you've got the result you're looking for. I find many $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs for continuity of a function often reveal themselves this way so it's worth remembering the technique.